# JavaScript Dynamic Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to understand how promises work in JS by playing with [swapi.dev](https://swapi.dev). I would like to create a dynamic chain of promises (not using async/await) but it does not provide me with any result. In particular, the idea behind is to get all names of the given person (for instance Luke Skywalker) and dump them into the console.

Could anyone help me? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
"use strict";

const request = require("request-promise");
const BASE_URL = "http://swapi.dev/api";

var currentPromise = Promise.resolve();

callApiPromise(`${BASE_URL}/people/1`).then((data) => {
  console.log("Getting vehicles' URLs");
  const vehicles_URL = data["vehicles"];

  console.log("Starting looping through URLs");
  for (let i = 0; i < vehicles_URL.length; i++) {
    console.log(`i=${i}, vehicle_URL=${vehicles_URL[i]}`);
    currentPromise = currentPromise.then(function () {
      console.log(".. getting vehicle name");
      return getVehicleName[vehicles_URL[i]];
    });
  }
});

function getVehicleName(url) {
  callApiPromise(url).then((vehicle_data) => {
    var arrVehicleData = new Array();
    arrVehicleData.push(vehicle_data);
    console.log(arrVehicleData.map((vehicle) => vehicle.name));
  });
}

function callApiPromise(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    callApi(url, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

function callApi(url, callback) {
  request
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      const json = JSON.parse(response);
      callback(null, json);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(err, null);
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise); it has been deprecated.

Comment: Don't use the [explicit promise antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: You don't need to create promises manually. You could use `node-fetch` to get the data and then use a `for loop` to fetch all the urls in that data. See the example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: Your `getVehicleName` function is missing a `return` statement at the start of its body.

Comment: It is weird that you are first wrapping a promise API to a callback API, and then use *that* callback API to create promises again. You should make up your mind and just stick with promises.

Comment: `getVehicleName[vehicles_URL[i]]` is not calling the function.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am going to process all your comments, really appreciate it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- A missing `return` statement in `getVehicleName`
- A syntax issue in `getVehicleName[vehicles_URL[i]]` (should be parentheses)
- As the promises for getting the vehicle names are independent, you would not chain them, but use `Promise.all`
- `arrVehicleData` will always only have one element. There is no reason for an array there where it is used.

You are also taking the wrong approach in using `request.get`. The bottom function turns that API from a Promise-API to a callback API, only to do the reverse (from callback to promise) in the function just above it. You should just skip the callback layer and stick to promises:

```
"use strict";

const request = require("request-promise");
const BASE_URL = "http://swapi.dev/api";

getJson(`${BASE_URL}/people/1`).then(data => {
  return Promise.all(data.vehicles.map(getVehicleName));
}).then(vehicleNames => {
  console.log(vehicleNames);
  // Continue here...
});

function getVehicleName(url) {
  return getJson(url).then(vehicle => vehicle.name);
}

function getJson(url, callback) {
  return request.get(url).then(JSON.parse);
}
```

Finally, you should not use `request-promise` anymore since the request module, on which request-promise depends, has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Answer (score 1):

The `getVehicleName` doesn't return a promise. Instead it invokes a promise that by the time it will be resolved, the for loop invoking it will already be removed from the call stack.

This is a sample of promise chaining:

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(2)
const methodReturnPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(3))

promise.then(firstPromiseData => {
  // do something with firstPromiseData
  console.log(firstPromiseData)
  return promise1
}).then(secondPromiseData => {
  // do something with secondPromiseData
  console.log(secondPromiseData)
  return methodReturnPromise()
}).then(thirdPromiseData => { 
  // do something with thirdPromiseData
  console.log(thirdPromiseData)
})
```